# Here Maps - Reposition map, If Info Bubble in not completely visible in current window

Tags: vue.js, infowindow, heremaps, infobubble

I am integrating "heremap" in Vue. In our scenario, we have lot of markers on map. On clicking any marker, some information about the markers is being shown on info bubble popup.

If a marker is at top of map and I clicked on the marker, it's info bubble is not completely visible in viewport as some of the bubble popup is hidden as can be seen in the below pic.

[Click on the Picture of Info Bubble of a marker on heremap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcSQ9.png)

In google map if info window of marker is not fully visible, it automatically readjust map to fit the window.

Any idea, how can I achieved this in heremap using vue?

Here is working example of heremap with marker.
Opening an Infobubble on a Mouse Click
https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/infobubbles/open-infobubble

Go to above link, move map to little bit up. Click one marker on map, it's info window bubble with show and map do not reposition itself to fully show info window bubble as you can see in the below picture.

[Click on the Picture of Marker on working example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJDQO.png)

Here the same working example of google map.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

Click on the marker, it's info window will start showing and if it is not fully in the window, map automatically readjust itself.

Comment: Try to apply `z-index` from style

Comment: No, it will not work. Info bubble goes out of viewport of window, if it is on right/left side.

Comment: Please provide some [reproducible example code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), wich would help a lot with answering your question in a meaningful way. Also, what have you already tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: @nosurs I have updated my question. I have added the working example of heremap and google map. In the heremap example, it is implemented in plain JavaScript but I am using Vue.

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to centre the map on the marker whenever you click on it.  This still won't guarantee the whole infowindow will appear on the screen, depending on how big it is.  But it's likely to work in most cases.

You should be able to get the map's centre using `map.getCenter()`

Using the examples given at

- https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/infobubbles/open-infobubble
- https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/events/position-on-mouse-click

you should be able to do something like:

```js
group.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
    var bubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble(coord, {
      // read custom data
      content: evt.target.getData(),
      position: group.getCenter()
    });
    // show info bubble
    ui.addBubble(bubble);
}, false);
```

Comment: Yes I can center the map everytime, info bubble is clicked. But the problem is, it will also re-center the map even the whole infowindow is already on the screen. I need to only center the map when infowindow is not fully visible on the screen.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to find out if it's completely visible or not.  Checking the docs at https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.25.0/api_reference/H.ui.InfoBubble.html  it has got a `getVisibility` method, but I suspect that just checks if it's opened or closed

Comment: I have checked the documentation, didn't find anything concrete.